# How to get all the commits of an authorized user from GitHub?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, github-api

For now I am using the following code to fetch commits from the github:

```js
await octokit
.paginate(octokit.rest.repos.listCommits, {
    owner: repo.owner.login,
    repo: repo.name,
    author: currentUser, 
    per_page: 100,
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error('octokit.rest.repos.listCommits failed, error: ', err);
    return [];
});
```

The 'currentUser' is the login of the github user.

I notice that sometimes the commit won't have the same login like the user and even without avatar in commit list. Is there a way to identify them? The example for this case is here: https://github.com/ersajo/teippo-test/commits/master

Is there a better way to gather the commits of a certain user?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue given the code posted. I have substituted string literals for the owner, repo, and author according to your example repo: https://runkit.com/60d93a827a3e50001a0bbcbc/60d93a82027b5a00191dbc54 This shows both commits. Can you describe what you mean by "sometimes" (is there a pattern?) and "fail to return" (do you get an error code?)...

Comment: @bburhans so "sometimes" means in some repo everything is gathered but in some others (like the one in my question) I can only get one and lose another. By "fail to return" I mean it does return the repo commits but some of them disappears in the result.

Comment: @bburhans If you can get everything then maybe I would try again to see if the commit was there.

Comment: @bburhans Just retried and the commit was filtered out after received from the API. So I just removed it from this question. The second part still needs some help though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is by design; I've added an answer that may help remedy the misunderstanding. Git repos (GitHub and otherwise) are collaborative by nature, and each commit can be attributed to anyone or no one; git authors are under no obligation to make a github.com account or even use a real email address. Such commits will be shown as if by a stranger on GitHub, using the name and email address from the original commit metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git users can commit to repositories under any name and email, and they do not have to be real or be associated with a GitHub user. Moreover, commits by other people can be included in a push to GitHub for several reasons, and it's common to merge other collaborators' work or sign off on commits authored by other people.

If that outlook.com email used to make the "unattributed" commits is yours, you can tell GitHub that it belongs to you at https://github.com/settings/emails, and it will act mostly like your primary gmail.com email address.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to find out if that commit is belong to this user?

Comment: Probably not for certain, unless you have a known-perfect database of email aliases for contributors and can also guarantee that nobody has used anybody else's email for the contributions in question. In this specific case, the git committer name is the same except for accents, so depending on your use case, it may be useful to assume it's the same person even though the email addresses differ.